# How to check statistics with JetBrains Idea 2016?

Tags: intellij-idea, lines-of-code, code-statistics

I am using IDEA 2016.3 and I would like to get some statistics on a Java project, like Lines-of-Code. How can I do it? I found nothing at all while browsing IDEA's menu. Some older questions said the View->Tool Windows -> Statistics but I don't have a Stats option there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Metrics Reloaded plugin from the plugin repository: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/93?pr=idea

Comment: You could also try this one: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=4509 I think it faster to use - just go to new tab at bottom.